# Ventana modal no se puede cerrar porque tiene opacidad encima

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Necesito ayuda con una ventana modal que no cierra.

Al dar click en el botón aparece el modal con opacidad. Acá el código del botón:

```
<!--Single Service-->
<div class="co-single-service-3">
    <span class="icon"><i class="icon-megaphone"></i></span>
    <div class="content fix">
        <h3>Diseño gráfico</h3>
        <p>Te ayudamos a mejorar tu línea gráfica y a crear un gran portafolio.</p>
        <a href="" id="modal fade" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#more-info" class="btn btn-border-white btn-sm">conoce más</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Y acá el del modal:

```
<!-- Modal info -->
<div class="modal fade" id="more-info" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="more-infoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="more-infoLabel">Diseño de experiencia de usuario</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in <strong>nec quod novum accumsan</strong>, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>in porro albucius qui</strong>, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn_1" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

acá 2 capturas de pantalla

[image: usuario hace click en botón]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

En tu código no muestras qué bootstrap estás usando ni qué estilos adicionales tienes cargados.

Asumiendo que fuese jQuery 3.3.1 y Bootstrap 3.3.7, tu ejemplo se vería así:

https://examples.ffflabs.com/bootstrap3_modal.html

Lo cual como verás no tiene ningún problema para cerrar el modal.

Analizando el "ciclo de vida" del modal, hay que apreciar lo siguiente:

- el modal existe desde el principio. Tiene posición `fixed`, display `none` (o sea, no se muestra) y `z-index` 1050.
- al abrir el modal el display pasa a ser `block` (o sea, sí se muestra)
- al abrir el modal se genera *temporalmente* un elemento con clase `modal-backdrop` que también tiene posición `fixed` pero `z-index` 1040, por lo cual queda por debajo del modal.
- al cerrar el modal el elemento backdrop se elimina del documento, con lo cual el contenido principal ya no está bajo la capa oscura.

En la captura de pantalla que nos muestras hay algo que hace que el modal quede por debajo del backdrop. Por ejemplo, alguno de los estilos que estás añadiendo para customizar tu theme está alterando el z-index de la clase `.modal`.

Sin embargo, me inclino por creer que en realidad el origen del problema es que tu modal está anidado dentro de otro elemento que tiene su propio z-index.

Por ejemplo

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="position:relative;z-index:1000">
     <!-- Código del modal -->
  </div>
</div>
```

https://examples.ffflabs.com/bootstrap3_modal_oculto.html

si te fijas, en un caso como ese el modal es hijo de un elemento cuyo z-index es 1000, y aunque el modal mismo tenga un z-index mayor, su nodo padre de por sí ya queda por debajo del backdrop.

Resumen:

- Posibilidad 1: hay un estilo que altera el orden original de los z-index
- Posibilidad 2: pusiste el modal dentro de un elemento que ya tiene su propio z-index y es menor que el z-index del backdrop.

Como práctica general, acostúmbrate a poner los modales afuera de cualquier container, teniendo como nodo padre al `body` del documento.

## Edit

Ya que estás usando `modal-dialog-centered` me parece que fuera bootstrap4. En realidad el comportamiento es el mismo:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="position:relative;z-index:1000">
      <div class="co-single-service-3">
        <span class="icon"><i class="icon-megaphone"></i></span>
        <div class="content fix">
          <p>Yo abro un modal que está fuera de este nodo y no altero su comportamiento</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2">
       Launch demo modal
      </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="position:relative;z-index:1000">
      <div class="co-single-service-3">
        <span class="icon"><i class="icon-megaphone"></i></span>
        <div class="content fix">
          <p><b>Contengo el modal</b> y mi z-index 1000 <b>influye en su posicionamiento</b>.</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
       Launch demo modal
      </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>in porro albucius qui</strong>,
                in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, in porro albucius qui, in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <strong>in porro albucius qui</strong>,
              in nec quod novum accumsan, mei ludus tamquam dolores id. No sit debitis meliore postulant, per ex prompta alterum sanctus, pro ne quod dicunt sensibus.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hola Amenadiel! gracias por tu ayuda, ya con lo que me dices estoy aprendiendo cosas nuevas :). Voy a revisarlo hoy y te comento mañana a ver si pude encontrarle la solución. Muchas gracias por haber hechos los ejemplos vinculados a las URL. Se aprecia mucho la ayuda.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Excelente respuesta muy completa.

Answer (score 0):

tenia el mismo problema, sólo movi donde defines el modal afuera de cualquier elemento como raiz en la etiqueta padre (body) y ya solo lo llamas con un boton al modal en cualquier etiqueta y funciona

Comment: Podrías agregar un poco del código para que se ilustre mejor tu respuesta.